# (Swift) Image not updating, comparing UIImage with UIImageView

Tags: swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var p36: UIImageView!    

func updateRow1View(){
    let Empty = UIImage(named: "Empty")
    let Red = "Red"
    let Yellow = "Yellow"

    if p36.image != nil && p36!.isEqual(Empty){
            p36.image = UIImage(named: Red)
        }
}

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
    updateRow1View()
}
```

In the code above, I have included all relevant code. Under assets, I have a file name called Empty, Red, and Yellow. In it's current state, I have set p36.image to be the Empty image, so if the code proceeds the way it is suppose to, the image will update to the Red image. However, this does not work, and when I press the button1 button, the image is not updated. Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: What does `p36!.isEqual(Empty)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can never be true:

```
 p36!.isEqual(Empty)
```

`p36` is a UIImageView, but `Empty` is a UIImage. You want to compare `p36.image` to `Empty`. But even then it might never be true, because `isEqual` is unreliable. What you want to do is compare the `pngData` of the two images.

Comment: yup need to compare image data

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare images and/with image views.

A better way is an enum to maintain the image status

```
enum ImageStatus : String {
    case empty, yellow, red 

    var image : UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: self.rawValue.capitalized)!
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var p36: UIImageView!
var imageStatus : ImageStatus = .empty    

func updateRow1View(){
    if imageStatus == .empty {
        imageStatus = .red
        p36.image = imageStatus.image
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, is there a way to extend this method if there are more than 1 UIImageView? I have a lot of them.

Comment: You could subclass `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Except vadian answer there you can compare two images with image data like using `UIImage` extension.

```
extension UIImage {    
   func isEqualToImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        let data1: NSData = self.pngData()! as NSData
        let data2: NSData = image.pngData()! as NSData
        return data1.isEqual(data2)
    }
}
```

Than use it as below.

```
class YOUR_CLASS_NAME {
@IBOutlet weak var p36: UIImageView!

func updateRow1View(){
    let Empty = UIImage(named: "Empty")
    let Red = "Red"
    let Yellow = "Yellow"
    
    if p36.image != nil && p36.image?.isEqualToImage(image: UIImage(named: "Empty")!) == true {
        p36.image = UIImage(named: Red)
    }
}

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
    updateRow1View()
}
}
 
//Extension should be here
```

Comment: Hello, I keep on getting an error that the extension is only valid at file scope. I am not sure what this means, but it may have to do we with me writing with Storyboard, not SwiftUI. Also, when you say //code here, which part of the code are you saying?

Comment: put extension out side of class file first. and code here means if both images will same it excute means whatever you want while both images are same.

Comment: and that answer is regarding `UIKit` storyboard. so it will work

Comment: @djdumpling you code will look like this check edited answer.